# Draw border edges of the Konvajs container Stage in html

Tags: stage, konvajs

I am using the Konvajs library. Am trying to put a border box around the main `Stage` element, but can't seem to make it work. The CSS only apply to the `<div>` and the `Konva.Stage` element does not seem to have specific properties for this.

Is the only way to add line shapes on the 4 borders of the Stage Layer?

My Konva container

```
<div class="TSPKonvaStage" id="KonvaContainer"></div>
```

My Konva Declaration below

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'KonvaContainer',   // id of container <div>
        width: 600,
        height: 180
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS for container element:

```
stage.getContainer().style.border = '1px solid black'.
```

Comment: How does that affect stage size? So if I have a 100px wide element and I make that the host for the stage, and I use the above to set a 10 px border, is my stage width 100px or 80px?

Comment: This seems to only draw the border to the whole '<div>', not the actual canvas which is not as wild as the '<div>'. The solution that seems to workf for now is to use 2 '<div> like , and use CSS to define the width and style of the main <div>

Answer (score 0):

This is an experiment with @lavrton's answer. I was curious if the stage was resized by the border. The answer appears to be no - at least on Chrome.

```js
// Set up the stage
var stage1 = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 300, height: 100});

// add a layer.
var layer1 = new Konva.Layer();
stage1.add(layer1);

console.log('Stage size before border=' + stage1.width() + ' x ' + stage1.height());

stage1.getContainer().style.border = '5px solid black';

console.log('Stage size after border=' + stage1.width() + ' x ' + stage1.height());

var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({x:0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40, strokeWidth: 10, stroke: 'lime'});
layer1.add(rect1)

stage1.draw()
```

```css
p
{
  padding: 4px;
  
}
#container1
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>

<p>This answers the question 'does the border reduce the size of the stage?'. Answer is no. The green rect appears with its left and top edges under the border - at least on Chrome. </p>

<div id='container1'></div>
```